# Проблема с методом субкласса

Tags: java, ооп, классы

Есть Класс `Game` с `Arraylist`-ом,в котором номинально содержатся объекты `player` 
Класс `Wolf` унаследован от `player`, и имеет метод `kill()`

```
public class Game {
    static ArrayList<player> players = new ArrayList<player>();
```

`Arraylist` содержит объекты как `player`,так и `Wolf` 
Так вот при переборе этого `ArrayList`-а надо сделать так,чтобы метод субкласса использовался как в коде показанном ниже,для объектов `Wolf` разумеется

```
for(player ppl : players) {
            if(ppl.Role == "Wolf") {
                ppl.kill();
```

Если это сделать нельзя,то буду благодарен за альтернативное решение проблемы

Comment: я бы сделал интерфейс для этих двух классов у которого есть метод `kill`.

Comment: Вот этот цикл `for(player ppl : players) {` у вас в каком методк запущен?

Comment: Что общего между Player и Wolf ?

Comment: `if (ppl instanceof Wolf) { Wolf wolf = (Wolf) ppl; ppl.kill(); }`?

Comment: Если возникает вопрос подобного рода (определение типа объекта для вызова специфического поведения), то, скорее всего, это ошибка проектирования структуры классов. Это, конечно, можно решить приведением типов. Но в последующем, скорее всего, ошибка проектирования все равно вылезет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Базовый игровой персонаж, с характерными признаками и действиями любого персонажа игры
class Character {
}

// Игрок тоже игровой персонаж
class Player extends Character {
}

// Киллером могут быть и не только волки
interface Killer {
    void kill();
}

// Волк это не только игровой персонаж, но и киллер
class Wolf extends Character implements Killer {
    void kill() {
        // Характерный для волка почерк в убийстве
    }
}

class Game {
    static ArrayList<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>(); // Почему static?
    ...
}

for(Character ch : Game.characters) {
    if(ch instanceof Killer) { // Любой киллер, а не только волки
        // если нужны именно волки, то if (ch instanceof Wolf)
        ((Killer)ch).kill();
    }
}
```